# How to load key-value pairs (MAP) into Athena from Parquet file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, key-value, parquet, create-table, amazon-athena

I have an S3 bucket full of .gz.parquet files.  I want to make them accessible in Athena.  In order to do this I am creating a table in Athena that points at the s3 bucket:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE user_db.table (
pan_id bigint,
dev_id bigint,
parameters ?????, 
start_time_local bigint
                                     )
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION ‘s3://bucket/path/to/folder/containing_files/’
tblproperties (“parquet.compression”=“GZIP”)
;
```

How do I correctly specify the data type for the parameters column?

Using `# parquet-tools schema`, I see the following schema of the data files:

```
  optional int64 pan_id;
  optional int64 dev_id;
  optional group parameters (MAP) {
    repeated group key_value {
      required binary key (UTF8);
      optional binary value (UTF8);
    }
  }
  optional int96 start_time_local;
```

Using `# parquet-tools head`, I see the following value for one row of data:

```
pan_id = 1668490
dev_id = 6843371
parameters:
.key_value:
..key = doc_id
..value = c2bd3593d7015fb912d4de229a302379babcf6a00a203fcf
.key_value:
..key = variables
..value = {“video_id”:“2313675068886132",“surface”:“post”}
start_time_local = QFOHvvYvAAAzhCUA
```

I appreciate any help you can give.  I have not been able to find good documentation for the MAP datatype being used in CREATE TABLE.

Comment: Can you share some actual parquet data file with few records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maps are declared as `map<string,string>` (for string-to-string maps, other types are also possible), in your case the whole table DDL would be:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE user_db.table (
  pan_id bigint,
  dev_id bigint,
  parameters map<string,string>, 
  start_time_local bigint
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://bucket/path/to/folder/containing_files/'
tblproperties ("parquet.compression" = "GZIP")
```

The map type is the second to last in the list in [the list of Athena data types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/data-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AWS Glue Crawler to automatically derive the schema from your Parquet files.

Defining AWS Glue Crawlers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html